# Cannot generate signing certificate sha 256 for Huawei Map Kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

I am trying to migrate Google Map to Huawei Map kit. Now I should generate local SHA 256 fingerprint for Huawei App Gallery and I am following this official documentation provided by HUAWEI: [Configuring App Gallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-sdk-config-agc-0000001061560289-V5)

1. I created my project in App Gallery
2. I already added my app to that project
3. I downloaded `agconnect-servises.json` file
4. I generated the .jks certificate in Android Studio
5. Then, for generating a signing certificate fingerprint for
   adding to Huawei App Gallery In the cmd prompt I went to the directory where the JDK installed, then opened bin directory and ran the command: `keytool -list -v -keystore <my .jks file path>`

Instead of getting the result which official doc. provided I am getting the following result in cmd.

[image]

I searched a lot and did not find any single information about this. What should I do to get the certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keytool command requires the addition of more options to get your SHA256. Here is the correct command with the additional options.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <keystore path> -alias <key alias> -storepass <keystore password>
```

While using the keytool is necessary in getting the SHA256, the Java keytool is a utilty created by Oracle and is not exclusive to the process of publishing on the Huawei AppGallery. Please refer to the official documentation for more information: [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_list)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me! But those who implement this, please, never forget to add double quotes "" to Keystore path. It must be inside the "". Otherwise did not work.

Comment: `""` is required around the path if the path contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate SHA-256 key in simpler manner you can follow the step as showed in the screenshot
[image: Click on Gradle -> signing report -> You will get SHA key in logcat]